# Datatype format in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am having source file with integer datatype in informatica as follows
JoiningDate :20161201
I want convert the integer into date datatype to load data into netezza target table. Is it possible to use date datatype with this format 20161201 in netezza.

I want this value 20161201 for date datatype in target table.If I am using date datatype in target it gives 2016/12/01 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear to me:

1) Are you using the nzload to "load" the data into the target, and only using powercenter to write the flatfile you are feeding into netezza ?

2) Are you writing dirictly to a table-target in the powercenter mapping/session ?

For now: I'll assume 2)

a) Are the datatypes and the order of ALL the columns exactly the same in the netezza table and in the powercenter target? 
b) how do you convert the "integer" date in informatica from INT to DATE/TIME datatype ? (if you don't convert is explicitly, that's probably your problem :))

Answer (score 0):

try TO_DATE(JoiningDate,'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.